# PHP/Python Download script won't finish

Tags: php, python, cgi

I'm trying to create a script so that the user can input a URL, and new file name, and that url will be downloaded (renamed as the new file name) to /var/www/dl, and a progress file (progress0001.txt ... progressXXXX.txt) will be updated as each download progresses

I have two files: dl.php, and rdl.py

dl.php:

```
<?php
$name=$_GET["name"];
if (file_exists("dl/$name")){
die("FILE EXISTS");
}
else {
$str=("/var/www/rdl.py '$name' '".$_GET["url"]."'");
//echo $str;
exec("$str &");
}
?>
added
```

rdl.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import urllib, os, sys
fname=sys.argv[-2]
url=sys.argv[-1]
name="progress"
end="txt"
while os.path.isfile("/var/www/p/%s.%s"%(name, end)):
    try:
        post=int(name[-4:])
        name=name[:-4]
    except:
        post=0
    post+=1
    name="%s%04i"%(name, post)
pname="%s.%s"%(name, end)
def report(count, blockSize, totalSize):
    global pname
    percent = float(count)*blockSize*100/totalSize
    pg=open("/var/www/p/%s"%pname, "w+")
    pg.write(str(percent))
urllib.urlretrieve(url, os.path.join("/var/www/dl", fname), reporthook=report)
```

I can run the exact command passed to `exec` in the php file in a command line, and it works fine. But when the PHP script executes it, I end up with a download file that exists, but is completely empty, and no progress file.
I have googled and tweaked this for hours and I'm at a complete loss. What is going on here?

Comment: What happens if you try:  `exec("$str");` (I removed the `&`)

Comment: same thing, that was actually the very first way I tried it

Comment: Also, what happens if you `pg.close()` after writing the data?

Comment: still the same issue. like I said, the python script runs perfectly from the command line, so I think it has to do with PHP, i just can't figure out what.

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being a file permissions issue, apache didn't have the authority to execute the scripts because it didn't own them.